# Losing my primary title

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've finally managed to carve out a decent kingdom in CK2, including Wales, Ireland, Brittany, Galacia and some bits of Scotland.

I have two King titles- the Kingdom of Wales (primary) and the Kingdom of Ireland. Brittany and Galacia aren't actually kingdoms because of the risk of losing the titles through elective succession.

Unfortunately, England managed to get a claim on Wales and are now invading. I'm probably going to lose the war.

What will I lose when I lose the kingdom of Wales? Will my vassals in Brittany and Scotland swear fealty to England? What about my Irish vassals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that will happen is that your current King will take on a new title, your vassals will then switch to whichever Kingdom you have now become - regardless of whether England successfully invade Wales or not. Those vassals in 'Brittany' and 'Scotland' are **YOUR** vassals not your 'titles' vassals.

You do however have an issue if you lose your second kingdom as you will be forced to become a 'Duke' which means any vassals of yours *(assuming you have Duke vassals)* will no longer be of lower rank and therefore you will no longer be their liege lord.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all of the territories that are considered to be part of Wales will become theirs. And this means not just de-jure Wales, but everything that is part of it.

An idea for a solution would be to set Ireland to primary and make some single-county guy King of Wales without all the other territory. Basically drop the king title for Wales, de-facto appending all those territories to Ireland and insuring that you come out ahead.

That's assuming you're about to lose.

To see what is considered part of Wales click on the title and see what is glowing in the non-de-jure mode.

Also, as the king, you'll get a strong claim on the kingdom in the event of a loss.